# Typescript: type that is union of object keys can't be use as a key for this object

Tags: typescript

I have a function that is called with one parameter. This parameter is object. This function is returning another object, which one property is value of passed to function object. I have problem when I'm trying to retrieve value of object, using obj[key] notation.

I do understand, that key has to be proper type to be used like this. I can't use simple key as string, if in interface I don't have [key: string]: any. But that's not the issue. My key is union of strings that were keys in passed object: 'user' | 'name' etc.

```js
interface Twitter<T> {
  name: T;
  user: T;
  sex: T extends string ? boolean : string;
}
interface Facebook<T> {
  appName: T;
  whatever: T;
  imjustanexapmle: T;
}

type TwFbObjKeys = keyof Twitter<string> | keyof Facebook<string>
```

My function looks like this:

```js
public static getArrayOfObjects(
        queryParameters: Twitter<string> | Facebook<string>,
    ) {
        const keys = Object.keys(queryParameters) as TwFbObjKeys[];
        return keys.map((paramId) => ({
            paramId,
            value: queryParameters[paramId],
        }));
    }
```

I would expect, that using paramId which is type: *'name' | 'sex' | 'appName' | ...* as a key for object, that has this keys, wouldn't throw an error. But unfortunately I have error:

**TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'name' | 'sex' | 'appName' | ... can't be used to index type Twitter | Facebook.
Property 'name' does not exists on type Twitter | Facebook**

I'm fighting with it for few hours now. Any idea how I can solve it?

Comment: How do you call the method? `getArrayOfObjects('appName')` or `getArrayOfObjects({appName: 'asd', .... })`?

Comment: It was getArrayOfObject({name: 'Jon', sex: 'male', ...}) @ford04 had the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Better define the function parameter `queryParameters` as generic type `T` with constraint `<T extends Twitter<string> | Facebook<string>>` instead of an union type `Twitter<string> | Facebook<string>`:

```
function getArrayOfObjects<T extends Twitter<string> | Facebook<string>>(
    queryParameters: T
) {
    const keys = Object.keys(queryParameters) as (keyof T)[];
    return keys.map((paramId) => ({
        paramId,
        value: queryParameters[paramId],
    }));
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=22#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHdhklAPKgPmQG8AoZC5EOAWwgC40BucygVwGdpHUXLkuADx7IIgyCAAmHAWCigA5sgD8yAEYB7DQBsIcEMkYc5ilgF9SoHPCTIAYogiaNAa3xEy-OAAdvAOVoGZlYKdAALOEgAN25g-mAaACtOMH0xHxpdHnNSUhg2EAQwYA0DBQgwAEEoKDgATwB5GAa1RIgijnxRcQgpGQwsHFxjeRAFIgAfe0dnNxHFAgIAChDkAEc2aDqABThauhwOHlIAShJVhFLjZBcIOpkAXmQWtqKAOlv7pY2t3f2K6AcM5wGRLT4aGBoE4AbQAunxKFAKmwoAZPhw3jQfEslt49rQAJKSM4PIhLTz8Sh4-ZEgA0q34UTg2k2jB+UB2+IOgOh1MJklh9P4ZhOJ3MQA)

**Explanations**

By using generics you keep the type of the passed in argument for `queryParameters` and just ensure that it will be a sub type of `Twitter<string> | Facebook<string>`. `paramId` with type `keyof T` now can access `queryParameters` properties.

With a union type `Twitter<string> | Facebook<string>`, `queryParameters` would remain undetermined and could be still `Twitter<string>` or `Facebook<string>` in the function body. That causes problems with `keyof` operator and property access in your case, as you can only access *common* property keys of all constituents given the union type. And there are no common properties for `Twitter<string>` and `Facebook<string>`.

To illustrate the issue a bit more, you probably meant to define `TwFbObjKeys` to be

```
// "name" | "user" | "sex" | "appName" | "whatever" | "imjustanexapmle"
type TwFbObjKeys = keyof Twitter<string> | keyof Facebook<string>

// not this: keyof only applies to Twitter<string> here: "name" | "user" | "sex" | Facebook<string>
type TwFbObjKeys_not = keyof Twitter<string> | Facebook<string>
```

But that would not solve the issue alone. Example:

```
declare const queryParameters: Twitter<string> | Facebook<string>

// type keysOfQueryParameters = never
type keysOfQueryParameters = keyof typeof queryParameters

// ok, let's try to define all union keys manually
type TwFbObjKeys = "name" | "user" | "sex" | "appName" | "whatever" | "imjustanexapmle"
declare const unionKeys: TwFbObjKeys

// error: doesn't work either
queryParameters[unionKeys]

// this would work, if both Twitter and Facebook have "common" prop
queryParameters["common"]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHdhklAPKgPmQG8AoZC5EOAWwgC40BucygVwGdpHUXLkuADx7IIgyCAAmHAWCigA5sgD8yAEYB7DQBsIcEMkYc5ivpQQaaNDSEYg2NNdFIBfUqBzwkyAGKIImhoA1vhEZPxwAA6RAHK0DMysFOgAFnCQAG7cifzANABWnGD6YlE0ujxmFBZWNnYOTlCupKSSEAjacFAoFiDGyACObNAAngAKXfE4HDyY2NC4xvIgCkQAPr7+gSFLigSkYCORKEEQIxwA8jAAisNQ45N008gAvMinIxowyIfHX4N3B5QKbQDgHI4oDA+NQXNT5ADSZxkbwARNQ6CjkBsUZxoJjsUJ8cgUVFYvEiSjUukIFkoBS8oVjCVBGVdCjWu1Ot1kL1+mwQMAbIjzrNobCEUjSENRhNgU9QQBtfmCkDCjgAXSlgNlIKgHAVKJq1hAKM1pCAA)

With help of a generic type, we can use `keyof T` to safely access the passed in `queryParameters` keys.

Comment: Thank you! Missing keyof was a typo on my part when 'copying' code here, but it didn't work nevertheless (as you explained why). When I put your improvements, the error is no longer here. Thanks for wholesome answer. Not only the solution, but really the answer. Not only I have code without errors, but also I learnt something new. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is coming from that line

```
type TwFbObjKeys = keyof Twitter<string> | Facebook<string>
// is of type type TwFbObjKeys = "name" | "user" | "sex" | Facebook<string>
```

you probably want

```
type TwFbObjKeys = keyof Twitter<string> | keyof Facebook<string>
// of type type TwFbObjKeys = "name" | "user" | "sex" | "appName" | "whatever" | "imjustanexapmle"
```

Comment: Thanks by catching this! In my code I had keyof Facebook<string>. The issue is somewhere else. I will update my question.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming you means `type TwFbObjKeys = keyof Twitter<string> | keyof Facebook<string>`)

Typescript raise an error because `paramId` has the type which contains all the keys of both interfaces:

**'name' | 'user'| 'sex' | 'appName' | 'whatever' | 'imjustanexapmle'**

but `queryParameters` can only be a type of either one interface:

**'name' | 'user'| 'sex'**

or

**'appName' | 'whatever' | 'imjustanexapmle'**

To solve the problem, you should separate both types:

```
interface Twitter<T> {
  name: T;
  user: T;
  sex: T extends string ? boolean : string;
}
interface Facebook<T> {
  appName: T;
  whatever: T;
  imjustanexapmle: T;
}

function isTwitter<T>(val: Twitter<T> | Facebook<T>): val is Twitter<T> {
  return (
    'name' in (val as Twitter<T>) &&
    'user' in (val as Twitter<T>) &&
    'sex' in (val as Twitter<T>) 
  )
}

function isFacebook<T>(val: Twitter<T> | Facebook<T>): val is Facebook<T> {
  return (
    'appName' in (val as Twitter<T>) &&
    'whatever' in (val as Twitter<T>) &&
    'imjustanexapmle' in (val as Twitter<T>) 
  )
}

function getValue<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
  return obj[key];
}

function getArrayOfObjects(
    queryParameters: Twitter<string> | Facebook<string>,
) {
  if (isTwitter(queryParameters)) { // if queryParameters is of type Twitter<string>
    const keys = Object.keys(queryParameters);
    return keys.map((paramId) => ({
      paramId,
      value: getValue(queryParameters, paramId as keyof Twitter<string>)
    }));
  } else if (isFacebook(queryParameters)) { // if queryParameters is of type Facebook<string>
    const keys = Object.keys(queryParameters);
    return keys.map((paramId) => ({ 
      paramId,
      value: getValue(queryParameters, paramId as keyof Facebook<string>)
    }));
  } else {  // if queryParameters is invalid
    throw new Error("invalid queryParameters!")
  }
}
```